# VB.net Advanced Data grid view filter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, advanceddatagrid

Hi all i am using the advanced data grid view as per [image: text] using the filter event the examples that i have seen are using a database but the data grid view is filled with data at runtime.

so I tried creating a binding the gridview being the data source

```
Dim obinding As New BindingSource

obinding.Datasourse = AdvancedDataGridView1.DataSource

obinding.Filter = AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString
```

but the filter is not working

Any and all help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the datagridview datasource to the bindungsource

```
Dim obinding As New BindingSource

obinding.DataSource = AdvancedDataGridView1.DataSource

obinding.Filter = AdvancedDataGridView1.FilterString
```

Comment: I tried that but the filter does not work

Comment: have you checked the content of filterstring? It must look like " columns1 >0 column2 <100" like a WHERE clause in sql

Comment: so I had to add the data to a data table and then AdvancedDataGridView1.DataSource = OTABLE which works but now i can't figure out how to add the combobox column data to the table otherwise again it will not filter

Comment: That is a new question, so start a new